# Linear Transformation Matrix with Change of Basis

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, change-of-basis

Beginning with the set that is a basis of $\mathbb{R}^2$: $b1 = \begin{bmatrix}1 \\-2\end{bmatrix}$ and $b2 = \begin{bmatrix}-3 \\-5\end{bmatrix}$

Let $T:\mathbb{R}^2→\mathbb{R}^2$ is a linear transformation such that 
$T(b1)=4b1+5b2$  and $T(b2)=6b1+3b2$ 
Then the matrix of $T$ relative to this basis is $$\begin{bmatrix}4 & 6 \\5 & 3 \end{bmatrix}$$

I understand this part, but I am unsure of how I would represent in terms of the standard basis.
I attempted to solve and got $$\begin{bmatrix}-19 & -15\\-33 & -27\end{bmatrix}$$ I did this by taking $4b1+5b2$ as the first column, however, I don't think this is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that $b1 = \begin{bmatrix}1 \\-2\end{bmatrix}$ and $b2 = \begin{bmatrix}-3 \\-5\end{bmatrix}$ are in terms of the standard basis, the matrix that change your basis to the standard one is
\begin{equation}
P = \left(\begin{matrix}
1 & -3\\
-2 & -5
\end{matrix}\right).
\end{equation}
This implies that the matrix of $T$ expressed in the standard basis must be following product:
\begin{equation}
P\left(\begin{matrix}4 & 6 \\5 & 3 \end{matrix}\right) P^{-1} =
\left(\begin{matrix}1 & -3 \\-2 & -5 \end{matrix}\right)
\left(\begin{matrix}4 & 6 \\5 & 3 \end{matrix}\right)
\left(\begin{matrix}5/11 & -3/11 \\-2/11 & -1/11 \end{matrix}\right)
\end{equation}

This is because the input vector, that must be multiplicated by the right hand side, must be changed from the standard basis to the original one (using $P^{-1}$) and the output vector must be changed from the original basis to the standard one (using $P$).